# How to correctly include .ASPXAUTH and ASP.NET_SessionId cookies with NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, asp.net, cookies, nsmutableurlrequest, .aspxauth

I've been at this problem for a few days. My app needs to login to an ASP.NET (version: 4.0.30319, MVC version: 3.0) server and then post via a NSMutableURLRequest to a restricted page (a page that requires you to be logged in to access).

Currently I can, successfully, login to the website. To login I use this code:

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"LogInEmail=%@&Password=%@",@"username@website.com",@"password"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/LogIn"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseMeta = nil;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseMeta error:&error];
```

I can check and see that both an ASP.NET_SessionId and .ASPXAUTH cookie, for that website, can be found in the sharedHTTPCookieStorage. I understand that both of these need to be sent with a request if I want to "be logged in".

The code for checking the cookies is here:

```
NSArray *cookiesForURL = [cookieJar cookiesForURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.example.com"]];

for (cookie in cookiesForURL)
{
    if([cookie.name compare:@"ASP.NET_SessionId"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        ASPdotNET_SessionId = [cookie value];
        NSLog(@"ASP.NET_SessionId: %@"  , ASPdotNET_SessionId);
    }
    if([cookie.name compare:@".ASPXAUTH"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        dotASPXAUTH = [cookie value];
        NSLog(@".ASPXAUTH: %@"          , dotASPXAUTH);
    }
}
```

To clear the cookies use this:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *each in [[cookieStorage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]] copy]) {
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
}
```

I tried posting to the restricted page by modifying `NSString *post` and `NSUrl *url` and using the same code above.

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[MessageId stringByAppendingString:@"=%@"],Comment];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.website.com/message
```

This is unsuccessful. I assume because I neglected the cookies in some way. I have tried adding in this code just under `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];`:

```
[request addValue:ASPdotNET_SessionId forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

and/or:

```
[request addValue:dotASPXAUTH forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

where `ASPdotNET_SessionId` and `dotASPXAUTH` are the cookie values retrieved from the sharedHTTPCookieStorage.

I feel like this is really simple, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing, it appears I was wrong when I thought I had been unsuccessful with the  authentication. It appears that either `NSURLConnection` or `NSMutableURLRequest` handle the cookies for me and I do not need to retrieve from the `sharedHTTPCookieStorage`or set them with my request.

Further if someone *were* to manually send the cookies they should be of at least this format and not just the pure value because ASP.NET expects the cookies to be in a certain format:

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ASP.NET_SessionId=%@", ASPdotNET_SessionId] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".ASPXAUTH=%@", dotASPXAUTH] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

or possibly this if the above does not work:

```
[request setValue:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ASP.NET_SessionId=%@", ASPdotNET_SessionId] stringByAppendingString:@"; path=/; HttpOnly"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
[request setValue:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@".ASPXAUTH=%@", dotASPXAUTH] stringByAppendingString:@"; path=/; HttpOnly"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

Where `ASPdotNET_SessionId` is the 24 char Session ID and `dotASPXAUTH` is the 448 char authentication string.